# How to handle invalid decimal value in Angular 4 typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]

The problem is if I not give any digit after '.' then it shows error

I need output like the following

23 -> OK

5 -> OK

3.5 -> OK

8. -> Not OK

The UI Code is  look like this
[image]

Comment: Please avoid pasting code as images, include it as text.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your regex pattern. Try to replace the last part `(\.\d{1,2})?` with `(\.)?(\d{1,2})?`. This means that the `.` can be set without having to enter the other two digits. You can play around with your regex pattern on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code into your Angular 4

```
    <input class="k-textbox" format="{0:c2}"  type="number" step="0.01" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69">
```